# Create sub-directories and organize files by date from file name

Tags: shell-script, scripting, date

I have been using the following script to organize my photos into "Date' Directories:

```
for x in *.JPG; do
  d=$(date -r "$x" +%Y-%m-%d)
  mkdir -p "$d"
  mv -- "$x" "$d/"
done
```

This script works great. My photo files follow the same naming convention 'IMG_20131125_090000.JPG' ie date and time photo taken. Is there a way to change the script above so that it categorizes into date directories still but using the date in the file name rather than use the date the file was modified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer fixed to get 2013-11-25  instead of 20131125**

If your script runs with a `bash` compatible shell, the easiest solution is to replace

```
d=$(date -r "$x" +%Y-%m-%d)
```

with

```
d="${x:4:4}-${x:8:2}-${x:10:2}"
```

**portable solution with expr:**

```
d=$(expr substr "$x" 5 4)-$(expr substr "$x" 9 2)-$(expr substr "$x" 11 2)
```

---

If you need only 20131125 instead of 2013-11-25 as directory name, you can also

*Solution with sed:*

```
d=$(echo "$x" | sed 's/.*_\([0-9]*\)_.*/\1/')
```

The `sed` commands replaces the filename with the number between the underscores (=the date).

*Solution with awk:*

```
d=$(echo "$x" | awk -F _ '{print $2}')
```

*Solution with cut*:

```
d=$(echo "$x" | cut -d_ -f 2')
```

Comment: @drewbenn Thanks for point this out - I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use :

```
export LC_ALL=C
for x in *.JPG; do
  d=$(date -d $( cut -d"_" -f2 <<< ${x} ) +%Y-%m-%d )
  mkdir -p "$d"
  mv -- "$x" "$d/"
done
```